# PostgreSQL UPDATE with case and subquery to get value from row right above

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, subquery, case

Considering the following table:

```
+-------+-----+----+
| genre | ref | id |
+-------+-----+----+
| CIT   | 000 |  1 |
| RP    | 111 |  2 |
| RV    |     |  3 |
| RP    | 777 |  4 |
| HY    |     |  5 |
| RB    | 222 |  6 |
| RV    |     |  7 |
+-------+-----+----+
```

I am looking for an UPDATE statement that will check if the row directly following a row with the genre 'RP' or 'RB' is a row with the genre 'RV' and if yes then it should update with the value from the row right above it (always right above; 'id-1'). So in this test case it would then look like this:

```
+-------+-----+----+
| genre | ref | id |
+-------+-----+----+
| CIT   | 000 |  1 |
| RP    | 111 |  2 |
| RV    | 111 |  3 |
| RP    | 777 |  4 |
| HY    |     |  5 |
| RB    | 222 |  6 |
| RV    | 222 |  7 |
+-------+-----+----+
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is to use window functions:

```
update t
    ref = tt.ref
from (select t.*,
             lag(ref) over (order by id) as prev_ref
      from t
     ) tt
where tt.id = t.id and
      t.genre = 'RV' and
      t.prev_genre in ('RP', 'RB');
```

If you happen to know that there are no gaps in the ids, then you can use joins:

```
update t
    set t.ref = tprev.ref
from t tprev cross join
     t tnext
where tprev.id = t.id - 1 
      t.genre = 'RV' and
      tprev.genre in ('RP', 'RB');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! There are no gaps in the ids. This is very close but not quite working. I can't exactly tell why but the updated row is now the one with RP and RB from one row above and not the one under it with RV... do you see the mistake?

Comment: @mr.parchman . . . I think I misunderstood the question.  Your question is only about two rows.  I was interpreting it as referring to three rows.

Comment: yes exactly ..it's only two rows ..one with either RP or RB as a genre and the following row with RV as a genre